# PHP SOAP send struct to request

Tags: php, web-services, soap, request

I trying to get response from SOAP service, I have this in my XML file:

```
<xs:complexType name="GetInsuranceDataF">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="req" type="tns:request" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="request">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="lbo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="zk" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I try to send data on two ways:

```
class Request {
    public $lbo;
    public $zk;
}

$request = new Request();
$request->lbo = '13900140107';
$request->zk = '20024179770';
$search = array('req' => $request);
```

and:

```
$search = array('req' => array('lbo' => '13900140107', 'zk' => '20024179770'));
```

but this not working, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please remember to provide more details about the errors that you are getting, no one here knows what exactly isn't working as it should.

Comment: I don't get error. I only receive empty object in response. Maybe i don't send parameters on right way and service don't found any results. I have another one method with one string argument, when i pass argument i get response with valid data, but for this one i get only empty object.